# Why does MaterialUI's Autocomplete getOptionSelected unselect the wrong option when using "multiple"?

Tags: javascript, typescript, user-interface, material-ui

I'm currently using these versions of material-ui:
 `"@material-ui/core": "^4.9.12", "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2", "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.57", "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.10", "@material-ui/styles": "^4.9.10",`

I can't seem to figure out why removing getOptionSelected results in the correct option being unselected, but adding it in causes the first selected option to get deselected rather than the one I clicked on.

(NOTE: enabledTeams is an array of strings)
`<Autocomplete freeSolo          multiple value={enabledTeams} options={enabledTeams} getOptionLabel={(option) => option} // getOptionSelected={(option) => enabledTeams.includes(option)} renderInput={(params) => ( <TextField type="search" {...params} label="Label" helperText="Some text" /> )} onChange={(e, v) => setEnabledTeams(v)} />`
Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-nightingale-ghidpl?file=/src/App.js

With getOptionSelected, it deselects the wrong option. Without it, it works properly.